# jQuery Video Taps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I've been trying to make a code when users click on a "Button Or Tap"; It goes straight to another video without leaving the site. I'm starting a video steaming site and can't seem to get this code to work. I do not host the videos on my database by the way. I even tried to make it work though iframe and of course hyperlinks. Any help would be very amazing, I've looked everywhere but all i can find is the "Youtube Scripts", I"ll truly be thankful for any advice or help.

Code -->>

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXExdj.html

Preview of what; I'm trying to make happen. http://i57.tinypic.com/2db1408.png

```
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
jquery-min-1-10-2.js"></script>
<script>
   $ (document).ready(function(){
   $ ("ul#videos li a").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   $("vimeo").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
   }}
   });
</script>
<style>
   iframe#vimeo {width: 700px; height: 394px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <ul id="video">
      <lil>
      <a id="island" href="VIDEO LINK">Video One</a></li>
      <li><a id="timeLapse" href="VIDEO LINK">Video Two</a></li>
      <li><a id="darkside" href="VIDEO LINK">Video Three</a></li>
   </ul>


<IFRAME ID="vimeo" SRC="http://streamin.to/embed-1sduh0qh36lg.html" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=504></IFRAME>
```

Comment: Paste your code rather than just a fiddlle.

Comment: Updated, It should be on there now.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide/show & play/pause HTML5 video tags based on which buttons are clicked.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q317ez6q/)

### HTML Code

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="video1button" href="#">Video One</a></li>
    <li><a id="video2button" href="#">Video Two</a></li>
</ul>

<video controls width="640" height="504" id="video1">
    <source src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type='video/webm'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video controls width="640" height="504" id="video2">
    <source src="http://justinwhitney.com/HTML5Example/HTML5Sample_WebM.webm" type='video/webm'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

### JavaScript Code

```
$("#video1").hide();
$("#video2").hide();

$("#video1button").click(function(){
    $("#video2").hide();
    $("#video2").get(0).pause();
    $("#video1").show();
    $("#video1").get(0).play();
});


$("#video2button").click(function(){
    $("#video1").hide();
    $("#video1").get(0).pause();
    $("#video2").show();
    $("#video2").get(0).play();
});
```

Comment: It wont work with the links, I'm using to steam movies. As you can see here @ https://jsfiddle.net/q317ez6q/2/ it shows up as "No video support". As i said above I'm using video steaming sites, I'm not hosting any on my main database so i cannot make a video player script.

Comment: The video streaming links that you have provided are domain specific. They do not work due to proprietary issues on any other domain other than **http://streamin.to**. It would help if you can provide another video streaming link which is not domain specific.